# display xml data present in table column into datagridview control c# winforms

Tags: c#, xml, database, winforms, datagridview

I am using C# winform's DataGridView control to display data present in a table to the user. All data gets present in the database table gets displayed to the user perfectly except the last column's data which contains data in XML format. In data DataGridView control the last column always gets displayed as empty but in fact in database the last column contains the xml formatted data. The GUI settings of the last column of the DataGridView control is shown below:

[image]

Can anyone suggest me how to display the xml formatted data in this DataGridView control?

Comment: Is the datatype XML or the datatype is varchar, but it contains data in XML format?

Comment: Datatype is xml with Allow Nulls set to checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way. You'll have to fetch the XML attribute/node values through XPath using a stored proc.

You can start from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117.aspx)